# Where to start with Google Calendar API using Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm developing an Android app in Kotlin that will require calendars to be shared between hosts and customers. For this I'm looking to use the Google Calendar API, however when looking through Googles documentation ([Google calendar api](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference)). I'm not able to find any documentation pertaining to Kotlin for the Calendar API, and on this page ([Google Workspace APIs for Android](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/android) ) states
"Note: We highly recommend calling Google Workspace APIs from a server environment rather than a mobile environment."

Could somebody advise what method should be used (If any) to access the Google Calendar API from an Android Kotlin application?

I've been researching this for days and am totally lost.

Answer (score 2):

Okay first off i am not a kotlin dev. But i do know alot about the google apis.  So I am going to try and give you some direction until someone with more kotlin specific knowledge responds.

First off you could try the [Google apis java client library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client) that should work with kotlin from my understanding.

I did find this [gax-kotlin](https://github.com/googleapis/gax-kotlin/issues) which claims to work with the Google cloud libraries.  Now that being said.  It seams to be dragging in the java auth stuff into this library and making it into kotlin somehow.

Which means it "should" work with the google apis libraries like google calendar.

I did find this [Running on Android (@Beta)](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-java-client/android.html) which shows how to authenticate the Java library from android.  The example is for drive if you need help switching it to calendar let me know.  I should be able to find something.

Comment: Yes, any Java library is 100% usable in Kotlin as long as it is for a Kotlin JVM project. (Kotlin also supports compiling for JS or native, in which case Java libraries would not be usable.)